# Unable to Connect to Elasticsearch 6.1.0[None of the configured nodes are available]

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm able to connect to elastic search `6.1.0` and index, update, delete and query the documents via cURL and plugin head but I'm unable to connect to the same via the java client, i.e,

```
    /**
     * Elasticsearch
     */
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '6.1.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/transport
    compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.client', name: 'transport', version: '6.1.0'
```

dependencies.
Below is `elasticsearch.yml`

```
#cluster.name: my-application
cluster.name: saasworthy-qa

node.name: qa-1

path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch

#network.host: 192.168.0.1
network.host: 10.10.10.2

#http.port: 9200

#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.10.10.2"]
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

The error received via java client is:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{SLvQfw9FREWVhpwTBtjNWg}{X.X.X.X}{X.X.X.X:9300}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:347)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:245)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:60)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:360)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:405)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:394)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:46)
    at com.sw.config.elastic.connection.factory.SaaSWorthyElasticsearchClientFactory.main
```

Also, `netstat` info,

```
netstat -antp | grep 9300
tcp6       0      0 10.10.10.2:9300         :::*                    LISTEN      19768/java
```

Kindly help me out in resolving the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm able to connect via the transport client after marking `client.transport.sniff` as `false`. As the server for dev environment, the cluster only contains one node.

For more [info](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-connect-to-elasticsearch-6-1-0-via-the-javaclient/112358/8).

Answer (score 2):

For Java Elasticsearch provides 2 sets of client API:

1. [Java Transport Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html)
2. [Java REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/index.html)

elasticsearch.yml for Java Transport Client (single node):

```
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Java Transport client example:

```
    // on startup

    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
            .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

    System.out.println(client.listedNodes());

    // on shutdown

    client.close();
```

To use Java Transport client we need the **[Bootstrap Checks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html)** need to be done which is quite difficult for a beginner.Its easier to use the Java REST client.

> **Note**: Elasticsearch plans on **deprecating** the **TransportClient** in Elasticsearch 7.0 and **removing** it completely in 8.0. More information
>   could be found **[here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/6.0/client.html)**(just scroll down to search for the
>   **warning** symbol).